# Custom Airflow Operator: Is it possible to overwrite __new__ method?

Tags: python, airflow

I kindly ask for your help with the following problem:

I tried to create a custom Airflow operator which should have the ability to dynamically change its configuration (in my case: the operator it inherits from) during DAG execution. For that purpose I tried to overwrite the **new** method to modify the necessary class properties. Unfortunately it seems, that upon execution in Airflow, no arguments are passed to **new**. This makes my implementation impossible (I need the arguments to check conditions).

This is a test example:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class TestOperator(BaseOperator):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("in new")
        logger.info(f"kwargs: {kwargs}")
        logger.info(f"args: {args}")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("in init")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        logger.info("in execute")


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="d_dev__test__new_operator",
    concurrency=1,
    max_active_runs=1,
    description="New Test",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.now()
)


t1 = TestOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="t_dev_1",
)
```

It yields the following output:

```
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,140] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance:   d_dev__test__new_operator.t_dev_1 2021-09-15T08:43:00.506224+00:00 [running]> on host  ddevtestnewoperatortdev1.63d7362bda96438e922e905320e847ce  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,199] {test_dummy_dag.py:16} INFO - in new  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,199] {test_dummy_dag.py:17} INFO - kwargs: {}  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,199] {test_dummy_dag.py:18} INFO - args: ()  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,829] {taskinstance.py:1302} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:  
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow  
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=d_dev__test__new_operator  
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=t_dev_1  
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-09-15T08:43:00.506224+00:00  
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-09-15T08:43:00.506224+00:00  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,830] {test_dummy_dag.py:26} INFO - in execute  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,861] {taskinstance.py:1211} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.   dag_id=d_dev__test__new_operator, task_id=t_dev_1, execution_date=20210915T084300,   start_date=20210915T084316, end_date=20210915T084317  
[2021-09-15 08:43:17,924] {taskinstance.py:1265} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

As on can see, the outputs for kwargs are empty. I would have hoped that this works according to "standard" Python behavior, where the arguments from the constructor are passed into the **new** method.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to make it work?
2. If not, does anyone know why it does not/cannot work?
3. It also strikes me as odd that the **init** method delivers no output (should be: "in init"), because it for sure has to be called at some point, right?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects (tasks) for execution in LocalExecutor (which I assume you use) are passed to subprocessed via Multiprocessing pipes, which pickle the object in scheduler and unpickle them in the task runnner.

This is why `__new__` gets empty arguments and `__init__` is not called - unpickling does not know the args in constructor, it will directly set attributes of the object from the serialized representation of the object.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

You can set the parameters passed to `__new__` on class level (but it's likely not what you want -see  `__getnewargs_ex__()`

I am afraid not much can be done about it.

Comment: Ok thats what I thought. Thanks anyway :)!